# How to change \section to be flush right and underlined

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, fancyhdr

Can someone please tell me how to get this design in articel class.
I´m not getting anywhere near it using fancyhdr or other packages.

Class: scrartcl

[image]

I would really appreciate help, I´m really spending to much time on this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post what you've tried?

Comment: I managed to put all section on the right-hand side using the following

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\raggedleft}{\thesection}{1em}{}

but I did not manage to make the underline look good

\underline seems to be different to the one up there?

Comment: Should only the section level or also sub- and subsubsections be flushed right?

Comment: Use the tool  supplied by titlesec: `\titlerule` (optional argument: the rule thickness).

Comment: @Bernard don't use `titlesec` at all if you're using `scrartcl`...

Comment: @Skillmon: the O.P. doesn't mention komascript, or did I misread?

Comment: @Bernard well hidden, but there is the line "Class: scrartcl" just above the image.

Comment: The layout you posted look much more like a chapter heading…

Comment: Yeah the example might be a Chapter, you´re right. 
The subsections should stay as they are.

Do you think I should change to chapter by using a different class e.g. book? I´m not sure if it will change the hole layout?

This document I´m working on is a pre work for my bachelor thesis btw.

Comment: I think titlerule works pretty well. Somehow the line is over not under the section name?

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\raggedleft\titlerule}{\thesection}{1em}{}

Comment: Can you guys guess what kind of font this might be?
It´s from a dissertation I found quite impressive in point of design.

Comment: @Corazon which class you should choose depends on what you want, if you want chapters then you should use `scrreprt` (or possibly `scrbook`), if you just want sections and no chapters then you should use `scrartcl`. Of course you can also pretend that each section is a chapter, but then layout will be different (for example a new chapter starts on a new page, while a new section continues on the same page as the previous section).

Comment: If it's for your bachelor's thesis, a class like `scrreprt` or `report` would be better suited. Article classes are for short articles (as the name suggests) of only a few pages length, your thesis is a report or even a book (though bachelor's thesis seldom have the length of a book).

Comment: @all thanks a lot for your help.

Using \titlerule and \raggedleft I got a decent result.

If anyone can recommend me a similar font I´d be 100% satisfied.

You think this font would be suitable for a bachelor thesis?

Comment: @Corazon there is not much font we can see, so I have no idea whether it is well suited. You can take a look in the [LaTeX font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/) and see whether you find a font there that gives good results.

Comment: Also, please note that it is advised not to use `titlesec` in combination with KOMA classes (such as `scrartcl` or `scrreprt`). Instead you should use the KOMA internal mechanism to change the formatting (as done in my answer, maybe there is even a more KOMA-scripty way to achieve this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A design that comes close using KOMA-script. As others already said, you should use a class providing chapters if you want chapters.

If you want a description under a `\section`, use `\sectiondescription` before the `\section`.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\let\KOMA@sectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]
  {%
    \ifstr{#1}{section}
      {%
        \null\hfill\parbox{.8\linewidth}
          {%
            \begingroup
            \raggedleft
            #3\par
            \bigskip
            #4\par
            \medskip
            \endgroup
            \hrule
            \ifx\section@description\@empty
            \else
              \begingroup
                \medskip
                \normalfont
                \itshape
                \footnotesize
                \section@description
              \endgroup
              \global\let\section@description\@empty
            \fi
          }%
      }
      {\KOMA@sectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  }
\newcommand\sectiondescription[1]
  {%
    \gdef\section@description{#1}%
  }
\let\section@description\@empty
\renewcommand\sectionformat
  {%
    \begingroup
    \bfseries
    \fontsize{60pt}{72pt}\selectfont\thesection
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\rmfamily\huge\scshape}

%% only for dummy contents
\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\sectiondescription{This section is about a duck}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your answer!

Which line exactly is causing the underline?

\titlerule for me makes the line over the section not under?

Comment: @Corazon in the redefinition of `\sectionlinesformat` there is a line `\hrule`, that one adds the line underneath. Please note that `\hrule` is a TeX primitive which has a bit of a weird syntax, if you want to set the thickness of the line, you should use `\hrule height 2pt` instead of just `\hrule`.